# How to make scheduled API requests?

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I need to find a way to create requests that will be send at a specified date. For example if I want to send this request in 1 week, I just have to specify the timestamp and the server should be able to automatically execute this request exactly 1 week after.

It is possible to do this with services like AWS or Firebase ?

Comment: AWS SQS with Lambda is something that might help you

Comment: check [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)